# codeigniter with sql

Tags: codeigniter

```
public function display( $date )
        {
            $this->db->select('*');         
            $this->db->from('event');
                 $this->db->where('start_date','$date');
                     $res = $this->db->get()->result_array();           
                 return $res;   
        }
     }
```

i am using this code in codeigniter to fetch the data from my database.but i get the error as "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string in sql".anyone pls help.

Answer (score 0):

$date variable without '' semicolons:

```
public function display( $date ) { 
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('event'); $this->db->where('start_date',$date); 
$res = $this->db->get()->result_array();
return $res;
}
```

Comment: Message: strtotime() [function.strtotime]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Asia/Calcutta' for '5.5/no DST' instead....i get this error now

Comment: remove semicolons for $data variable in where statement

Answer (score 0):

```
public function display( $date )
        {
            $this->db->select('*');         
            $this->db->from('event');
                 $this->db->where('start_date',cast($date as date));
                     $res = $this->db->get()->result_array();           
                 return $res;   
        }
     }
```

it should be proper date format to cast the $date should be in the format of yyyy-mm-dd otherwise construct adate format of your sent date like this

```
$newdate=date_create($date);
$perfectdate=date_format($newdate,'Y-m-d');
```